# How to get the data from http request in a standard way in golang?

Tags: ajax, http, curl, go

I am trying to get the data from http request in golang. I am using net/http package. In my server handler I am trying to get the data from r.Body

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("FATAL IO reader issue %s ", err.Error())
}
```

it works fine when I curl the service with some input data.

```
curl --data '{"AppName":"Proline","Properties":null,"Object":"","Timestamp":"2016:03:27 00:08:11"}' -XGET http://localhost:8081/api/services/test/
```

But when I try to call this service from ajax call r.Body is empty.

```
requestJSON = '{"AppName":"Proline","Properties":null,"Object":"","Timestamp":"2016:03:27 00:08:11"}'
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8081/api/services/test/",
  data: requestJSON,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){alert(data);},
  failure: function(errMsg) {
      alert(errMsg);
  }
});
```

So I changed to read the input data from `r.Form`

```
r.ParseForm()
var body []byte
for key, _ := range r.Form {
    body = []byte(key)
    break
}
```

But now the curl request fails. Is there a standard way to retrieve input data from http request in golang?  I am using Go 1.6. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried sending as POST?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer -  POST is working fine with `r.Form`. Is it not possible to send data in GET?[it might not be a good practice though].

Comment: An http GET request with a body is unusual. I think against the spec as well. So I think your browser is not allowing it. Yes its not a good practice. Use POST.

Comment: @ArunaHerath - Hmmm. if I want to get some values through an API by passing some id etc. I need to add the id in the input right.

Comment: You either POST (with data in the body), or GET (potentially with a header containing your credentials to authenticate with). You can't GET with a body.

Comment: @DineshAppavoo Use URL query params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a meaningful body with a GET request is disallowed by the spec. So your browser is probably sending an empty body. You can use POST instead. Its unsurprising that `r.ParseForm()` is not working because it expects the body to be encoded by `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Not `json`.

If GET is more appropriate to send the user inputs to your server's request handlers you can use url query parameters.

Quoting JQuery.ajax() [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for **data** parameter,

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs.

So you can do,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8081/api/services/test/",
  data: {AppName: "Proline", Properties:null, Object: ""}, // An object, not a string.
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){alert(data)}
})
```

An in the server,

```
params := r.URL.Query()
params.Get('AppName') // returns 'Proline'
```

See docs: https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query